# Associative container with finding element with the lowest value

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, data-structures, stl

I'm looking for a best solution. I'd like to store objects: key-value in container. I need a "good" access to every element by key and I need to find element with the lowest value.

What container would you recommend? Is there any better solution (in STL or Boost) than std::map? (Access to element is ok but looking for the lowest value is O(n) I guess)..

[Edited]

Sorry, I missed to add one very important thing. I actually want to get the lowest element (with the lowest value) and remove it...

Let's say my usage is:

1) access to some element (by key)

2) access to element with the lowest value and remove it

3) go to 1st step if container is not empty

What should I use? What do you think?

Comment: Well you can use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) with a custom comparator function so it's sorted on value instead of on the key. Then the "lowest" entry will always be `yourMap.begin()`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: How is that possible, since `std::map` needs a binary predicate that, taking two element keys as argument?

Comment: @TNA Well if you have the key, then you can get the data. If you have the data you can use it to do the comparison.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg wait, are you proposing that the comparator function should query the map for the data? That's... not a very good idea, to put it mildly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I didn't say it was a good idea, but it is one solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a second container (`std::vector` or `std::set`) with Iterators to your Elements, and sort it according to your needs.

Comment: Hmm... How about std::map and std::priority_key with iterators to elements from std::map?

Comment: @peter55555 You mean `std::priority_queue`? Yes that should work if you provide a binary predicate for you iterators.

Comment: The point with `std::priority_queue` is, that you can only access the "top" (in your case lowest value). If that is what you need thats totally fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. (Yes, I mean std::priority_queue of course. Sorry for mistake).